# Bootstrap tooltips do not appear for Ladda buttons (Chrome / Edge - but works in Firefox)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, ladda

Twitter Bootstrap tooltips appear on mouse-over for all elements **except** [Ladda buttons](https://github.com/hakimel/Ladda) in Google Chrome and MS Edge (under the same circumstances they *do* appear in Firefox).

Tested with Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2, 3.4.1, 4.3.0; tested with Ladda buttons 0.96 and 1.0.6; tested with JQuery 1.9.1 and 3.3.1 (all combinations of these, with no effect on behaviour).

Two JSFiddles to illustrate this, [the first](https://jsfiddle.net/AMarchant/p7vtx3wk/5/) using JQuery 1.9.1, Bootstrap 2.3.2 and Ladda 0.96

[The second](https://jsfiddle.net/AMarchant/ud1agx2y/14/) using JQuery 3.3.1, Bootstrap 4.3.0 and Ladda 1.0.6

And a snippet of Fiddle script to satisfy StackOverflow's editor:

```
var btn = $('#buttonladda');
var l = Ladda.create(btn[0]);
l.start();
btn.tooltip({opacity: 1.0, fade: true, placement: 'top', animation: false, container: 'body', html: false});

var adiv = $('#adiv');
adiv.tooltip({opacity: 1.0, fade: true, placement: 'top', animation: false, container: 'body', html: false});
```

In Firefox, it's possible to observe the tooltip elements being dynamically added to the DOM on mouseover (on a Ladda button) via Developer -> Inspector tools. Nothing happens within the DOM in Chrome / Edge on mouseover.

I can't determine why this might be, but I'd certainly appreciate it if someone else can spot what I'm missing. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question after further investigation: this is nothing to do with Ladda, specifically, but rather that Ladda adds a "disabled" attribute to the target button element when instantiated.

Firefox will happily display a Bootstrap tooltip on a "disabled" element (or rather, it would seem, Firefox triggers the relevant mouse events), but Chrome does not.

Wrapping the target button in a container div, and adding my Bootstrap tooltip to this container solves the problem.